# How can we import all projects at a time(having a number of projects) of a folder to my STS workspace?

Tags: java

How can we import all projects at a time(having a number of projects) of a folder to my STS workspace?

Answer (score 0):

File --> Import --> General --> Existing Project into Workspace or Projects from Folder or Archive , then Browse the path

[image]

Comment: i try Projects from Folder or Archive is ok

Comment: you can check my screen shot , i use  Projects from Folder or Archive

Comment: when you choose folder, u have wait a moment, the IDE need time to loading